# Create a page for a theme only

Tags: multisite, templates, mobile

I am in the process of creating a wordpress mobile theme for one of my wpmu networks. I have created 2 + pages that show our other sites and a custom login form. Right now i have labeled them page-other-sites.php and page-login.php and created 2 pages in the backend. When you click on the link it loads the page-(slugs).php

Now instead of having to create a page every time is there a way to have my themes function.php file create a set of default pages.?

Comment: Could you describe that more in detail? I just don't get around it.

Comment: I have currently 2 pages. One shows `other sites` and the other shows `login` they are named so that when i create a page in wordpress with the write slug they load the page. This page does not have any wordpress features just some php coding. What i was wondering is there a way for me to put some code into the functions.php files that will tell wordpress there are some external pages. These pages should load domain.com/login domain.com/other-sites not a full path to wordpress theme directory. Also it will not be a active theme but a theme that gets activated when a mobile devices enters

Comment: Puh... have a hard meeting behind me, so I'm pretty tired at the moment. (Maybe stupid) Question: You are talking about how to add a set of `page-other-sites.php`? In this case, take a look at [`wp_insert_post()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post)

Comment: @kaiser - I looked into the link you sent me and that is somewhat what i am looking for. But i do not wish to create a page in the db permanently but create a dynamic page in a sense. Make wordpress think that this is an actual page. I say this because i am not creating a mobile theme for a mobile blog but creating a mobile theme that a plug in calls if the user-agent is a mobile device.

Comment: fake pages? They need fake permalinks, IDs, etc. Hard, maybe impossible to do. Simply switch stylesheets or templates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So instead of creating a theme for it i ended up using the `template_redirect` with an if statement to check the url for a certain thing.

```
function page_redirect() {
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == $home . '/other-sites')  {
        require(TEMPLATEPATH . '/includes/other-sites.php');
    }
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == $home . 'login')  {
        require(TEMPLATEPATH . '/includes/login.php');
    }
}
add_action('template_redirect', 'page_redirect');
```

Simply all this does is check to see if the requested URI is `wpsite.com/other-sites` or `wpsite.com/login` and if this is true then load this template instead. Since i am using some WordPress features though in these custom templates i have also made a check for the title since WordPress will return a page not found title.